# How to change the feature product "Number of new products to show " on home page in shopify?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

I am using the Shopify admin panel for my website. Currently, On the home page, I am getting 20 feature product.

I have to change the limit of "Number of new products to show".

Is there any other option to change it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yeah there is way to change the product limit.

First You have to Follow this way.**EDIT CODE > SECTIONS > (there is particular section which you want to edit that if you have to find it. in your case maybe that section name "WIDGET PRODUCT" ) Example:feature.collection.liquid**

In that file there the in the {% schema %} you find below json code.

In that code you have to change the limit of product ***"max" : 90,*** ( set the particular number as per your requirement).

```
{
      "type": "range",
      "id": "products_limit",
      "label": "Limit products",
      "min": 2,
      "max": 50,
      "step": 1,
      "default": 48
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will check this and update you.